# sockets with kivy-recv line don't work

Tags: kivy

I made an app working with kivy that sends "name" to the server(with socket), the server inserts the "name" to the data base and sends back the "name" to the client(the app) and the client prints it.

I don't get any error but the app doesn't work. it is not open.

My client(the app):

```py
# kivy.require("1.8.0")
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout  
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.graphics import Line
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import socket



Builder.load_string("""
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'Sign Up'
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'settings'
        Button:
            text: 'Login'
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'
                root.manager.current = 'settings'

<Searchi>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: 'send massage'
            font_size: '20sp'
            size_hint: (0.4,0.111)
            pos_hint: {'y': 0,'x':0.6}
            on_press:
                root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                root.manager.current = 'settings'




<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        FloatLayout:
            LoginScreen
            Button:
                font_size: '20sp'
                size_hint: (0.4,0.111)
                pos_hint: {'y': 0,'x':0.6}
                text: 'Back to menu'
                on_press:
                     root.manager.transition.direction = 'right'
                     root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")

class LoginScreen(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2
        self.my_socket = socket.socket()
        #host = socket.gethostname()
        #port = 8585
        self.my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8081))

        self.add_widget(Label(text='username'))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.add_widget(Label(text='Password'))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

        self.submit_button = Button(text='sumbit',size_hint=(.5, 
.25),font_size=20)
        self.submit_button.bind(on_press=self.submit_username)
        self.add_widget(self.submit_button)

    def submit_username(self, *args):
         # Make sure to validate the input before submitting to the server
        self.my_socket.send(self.username.text.encode('utf-8'))
        sm.current = 'searchi'
        sm.transition.direction = 'left'

# Declare both screens
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Searchi(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Searchi, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.my_socket = socket.socket()
        self.my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8081))
        self.msg=self.my_socket.recv(1024)
        self.name=self.msg.decode('utf-8')


        self.add_widget(Label(text="hello"+self.name,size_hint=(1, 
1.7),font_size=20))


# Create the screen manager
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(Searchi(name='searchi'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))

class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

My server:

```py
import socket
import db      # import my db
import time


server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1',8081))
server_socket.listen(5)

(client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
while(True):
    client_username = client_socket.recv(1024)
    msg=client_username.decode('utf-8')
    db.data_entry_login(msg,"dsfsds","dsfsfsdd","2")  #insert to my db
    msg=msg+"\r\n"
    client_socket.send(msg.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as you mentioned the `recv` method.
That method put the whole main thread on hold, so the app wont run.
Whenever something is waiting or looping in the mainthread, the app will stop updating. And `recv` is waiting for a message.
So you need to put the `recv` in a thread.

You could do like this:

```py
import threading
from kivy.clock import mainthread 

class Searchi(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Searchi, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.hello_label = Label(text="Connecting...",size_hint=(1,1.7),font_size=20)
        threading.Thread(target=self.recv_msg).start()

    # make sure you execute UI updates in mainthread
    @mainthread
    def recv_msg(self):
        self.my_socket = socket.socket()
        self.my_socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8081))
        self.msg=self.my_socket.recv(1024)
        self.name=self.msg.decode('utf-8')
        self.hello_label.text = "hello"+self.name
```

Comment: this is still not working, if i delete the recv line in the client. it is working. can you try run it on your pc? maybe there is problem on my pc...

Comment: can you show me how can i wrote that? i am was try to do that and it is still dont working

Comment: the app is open now, but now the server didn't get the name from the client at the first time... and the app didnt get the name from the server

Comment: @ShaharBitan I cannot test your db conn. But try send some dummy variable.. like `client_socket.send("test\r\n")`

Comment: i am think i need a server that can connect to more then one client in the same time. hoe can i write that? i mean how the client and the server need to look like? thanks for your help

Comment: @ShaharBitan a server basically creates another client for the other client to talk to. Thats all a server does. Then it can keep listenin for new clients. https://pymotw.com/2/socket/tcp.html

Comment: then what can be the problem ? my server dont get the name from the client , he get the name from the client just if i delete the class"searchi".. how can i send data from one class in the client(Loginscreen) to the server, and recv data from the server in other class in the client(searchi)?

Comment: please can you help me ? How can i send data from one class in the client(Loginscreen) to the server, and recv data from the server in other class in the client(Searchi)?